# Webhook server: readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, nginx, github

I installed the webhook server by [adnanh/webhook](https://github.com/adnanh/webhook) and configured it the proper way I think - Github gives me a 200 response, the webhook-url is accessible and another execution is already working. I also ran the .sh file by itself via CLI - also works.

Link to webhook: https://webhooks.dmnktoe.de/hooks/pull-dmnktoe

This is my hook:

```
{
    "id": "pull-dmnktoe",
    "execute-command": "/var/www/html/webhooks/commands/pull-dmnktoe-de.sh",
    "command-working-directory": "/var/www/html/dmnktoe-de-webhooks/webhook",
    "trigger-rule": {
      "and": [{
        "match": {
          "type": "payload-hash-sha1",
          "secret": "mysecret",
          "parameter": {
            "source": "header",
            "name": "X-Hub-Signature"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  },
```

and this is my corresponding "**pull-dmnktoe-de.sh**"-file that should be triggered after a new commit:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /var/www/html/dmnktoe-de/$1
git stash
git pull
gulp serve:dist
```

I wondered why the page doesn't get updated. I looked into the nginx error log and found that:

```
2019/01/25 15:17:33 [error] 12297#12297: *4771 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.42.172.89, server: webhooks.dmnktoe.de, request: "GET /hooks/pull-dmnktoe HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9001/hooks/pull-dmnktoe", host: "webhooks.dmnktoe.de"
```

I think you will need the server block to comprehend my problem.
This my webhooks.dmnktoe.de server block.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name webhooks.dmnktoe.de;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/webhooks.dmnktoe.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/webhooks.dmnktoe.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

  location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;   
  }

  location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://webhooks;
  }
}

upstream webhooks {
  server 127.0.0.1:9001;  
}
```

Comment: "Connection Refused" is a pretty specific error - usually means nothing is listening on port 9001.  Have you confirmed that the webhooks server is *listening* on port 9001?

Comment: yes. `tcp6       0      0 :::9001                 :::*                    LISTEN      22251/webhook`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the netstat output, webhook appears to be listening on the IPv6 interface, thus you have to rewrite your upstream from `http://127.0.0.1/hooks/...` to `http://[::1]/hooks/...`

- OR -

tell webhook to bind to 127.0.0.1 IP by passing `-ip 127.0.0.1` when starting webhook.

Cheers,
Adnan (author of adnanh/webhook :-))